# Bcp Utility with login_id and password using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I use the bulk copy program utility (bcp) bulk copies data between an instance of Microsoft SQL Server and a data file in a user-specified format, in my case TXT format.

I need use on my code the `login_id` and `password` for specified user on the windows server.

According to this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) I have tried this code:

```
Declare @bcpCommand varchar(8000) SELECT
@bcpCommand = 'bcp "SELECT TOP 100 * FROM [dotable];" 
queryout "D:\inetpub\wwwroot\public\prot.txt" -T -c -t -U Servername/Username -P xxxxx;'
print @bcpCommand;
Exec master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand;
```

But the error is:

```
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file
```

On the folder `D:\inetpub\wwwroot\public` the user has full control of the folder.

The SQL server version:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-GDR) (KB4058560) - 13.0.1745.2 (X64) 
Dec 29 2017 10:51:35 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: The switch `-T` means you are using a **trusted connection**, so supplying a username and password makes little sense. Also the Username and Password you supply are AD credentials, however, the Username and Password is for SQL Authentication. If you want to command to run under a different Windows Login, you need to run the command under the credentials of a different user. In truth, running `bcp` from `xp_cmdshell` is normally an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: _On the folder D:\inetpub\wwwroot\public the user has full control of the folder._ By this you mean the account that the SQL Server service is executed with, right?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Not... I mean the user of the server

Comment: If you `exec xp_cmdshell 'whoami.exe'` what is the result? Users without the sysadmin role could also be subject to the [xp_cmdshell Proxy Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql#xp_cmdshell-proxy-account).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the result is `nt service\mssqlserver`

Comment: Why would you execute `bcp` from SQL using `xp_cmdshell`, why not do it from an actual command line or scheduled job